# Tizen TV Xamarin speech to text (No engine available exception)

Tags: speech-to-text, tizen, television

I'm trying to test a speech to text app made in Xamarin for Tizen TV 6.0. The problem is that upon debug launch I get "No available engine" exception. I tried looking it up, and it seems related to unavailability of the SST engine in Tizen Emulator.

Is there a way to test this app without access to an actual TV screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm Tizen platform engineer.
Unfortunately, the emulator for TV does not include STT engine.
Therefore, if you want to test the STT function on your application, please check the operation through the emulator for Mobile.